# How to remove url slug "page" for all wordpress pages?

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like my site shows all wordpress pages including archives and categories without  url /page/ slug.

Examples:

www.virmodrosti.com/page/03/ -> www.virmodrosti.com/03/

www.virmodrosti.com/zdravje/page/ -> www.virmodrosti.com/zdravje/2/

I know there is an option for .htaccess but is there also an option to add some code to functions.php?

Kindly let me know, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to set permalinks through your WP admin panel.

Navigate to `Settings->Permalink Settings` and Select the `Post name` in common Setting or In custom structure add this `/%postname%/`

Save it and Refresh your website.

Comment: That doesn't do anything except remove /category/ not slug /page/

Comment: I'm looking for the same solution as well. Hope someone who know about this can respond to this topic.